# unicodedata.unidata_version prints wrong unicode version?

Tags: python, string, unicode

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.version_info
sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=2, releaselevel='final', serial=0)

>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.unidata_version
'5.2.0'
```

Which means my Python version should have Unicode 5.2.0.

But When I go to the [list of newly added unicode chars in version 5.2.0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/version/5.2/index.htm) and print such char, it is not recognised:

```
>>> print u"\u0803"
ࠃ
```

[Chars from 5.1.0](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/version/5.1/index.htm) are recognised however:

```
>>> print u"\u03CF"
Ϗ
```

So should I always count one version below the one is actually outputted by `unicodedata.unidata_version` or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing what your terminal can print with what Python knows about unicode characters.

Your *terminal font* doesn't recognize those code points. Python can handle them just fine:

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.category(u'\u0803')
'Lo'
>>> unicodedata.name(u'\u0803')
'SAMARITAN LETTER DALAT'
>>> unicodedata.category(u'\u03CF')
'Lu'
>>> unicodedata.name(u'\u03CF')
'GREEK CAPITAL KAI SYMBOL'
```

Ironically enough, the font used by my browser doesn't define an image for either codepoint. Your post shows two placeholder characters for me:

[image: two placeholder characters]

Comment: Btw, are you aware of a command for Linux to check the unicode version used by the terminal?

Comment: @Bentley4: It's the *font* used by the terminal that's your problem. Would http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/unicode.html be able to answer your questions in that regard?

Comment: The effort needed to read that amount of text is not in proportion to the need for me to get an answer to that question right now : ). It just would've been convenient if there was such a command. But thank you for the resource(+1), I might read it later.